# SQL joins with 3 tables from which one is optional

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have already existing MySQL DB, where I try to get all 'Job' entries related to 'ProjectId' or 'ProjectScopeChangeID' for given project number. Some projects have ProjectScopeChange and some not.

This is for me unusual relation of 3 tables and I am already lost after trying all kinds of join combinations on them. This is the schema of problem part:
[image: the problem part]

Data in the ProjectScopeChange table look like this:

```
projectScopeChanngeID project
2                     4
4                     4
```

PlannedDisciplineJob table look like this:

```
 plannedDisciplineJobID projectID   projectScopeChangeID
 1                      4               {null}  
 2                      4               {null}  
 14                     4               {null}  
 4                     {null}           2
```

And because Project - PSC is one-to-many relationship, project doesn't have any column about PSC.

Basically, if I would want to get all Jobs for the project only, I would use this code:

```
select p.projectID,
pdj.plannedDisciplineJobID

from project p,
planneddisciplinejob pdj

where p.projectID = pdj.projectID
  and p.number = ?
```

Also, if I'd want to get all jobs for the PSCs, I'd use:

```
select p.projectID,
psc.projectScopeChangeID,
pdj.plannedDisciplineJobID

from project p,
projectscopechange psc,
planneddisciplinejob pdj

where pdj.projectScopeChangeID = psc.projectScopeChangeID
  and p.projectID = psc.project
  and p.number = ?
```

but, when I try to put it together somehow like this:

```
select p.projectID,
psc.projectScopeChangeID,
pdj.plannedDisciplineJobID

from project p
left join projectscopechange psc
on p.projectID = psc.project,
planneddisciplinejob pdj

where p.number = ?
  and (pdj.projectID = p.projectID
    or pdj.projectScopeChangeID = psc.projectScopeChangeID)
```

it just results in a combination

```
projectID   projectScopeChangeID    plannedDisciplineJobID
4           2                       1
4           2                       2
4           2                       4
4           2                       14
4           4                       1
4           4                       2
4           4                       14
```

instead of expected (4 is PSC of ProjectID 4, but has no job)

```
projectID   projectScopeChangeID    plannedDisciplineJobID
4           {null}                  1
4           {null}                  2
4           {null}                  14
4           2                       4
```

Thank you in advance for any hint leading to the correct result

Comment: Well, I finally got the result by using UNION on the first 2 select statements (and modified select columns to be only from PDJ table), but it doesn't seem to me as a right way of doing it. I still find it as proper JOIN challenge, so I still wonder on how could it be done with JOINs only (without UNION). Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.projectID, psc.projectScopeChangeID, pdj.plannedDisciplineJobID
FROM project p
INNER JOIN planneddisciplinejob pdj ON pdj.projectID = p.projectID
LEFT JOIN projectscopechange psc ON pdj.projectScopeChangeID = psc.projectScopeChangeID
WHERE p.number = ?
```

Comment: Thank you Saharsh, but that gives me the same result like when loading only projects (except having projectScopeChangeID column with null) - exactly just first 3 lines of the expected result

Comment: Sorry Saharsh, forgot about it. Now it's there. Basically, PDJ has ID either for project or for psc, where the other is null

Comment: Well, your suggestion unfortunately didn't work. Because the actual final query is a bit more complicated and uses more table joins than this example, so the only problem when using UNION is that after all everything has to be written twice including parameters. But that's a small problem to live with ;o)